# Update Database Row using SqlDataProvider for SQL Server in F#

Tags: f#, f#-data

I'm new to F# and I'm experimenting with the `SqlDataProvider`.

The thing I'm trying to accomplish is updating Db row which I'm prefetching it with the Individuals property. Then I'm changing on of the fields and submitting the updates, but it seems that `SqlDataProvider` is not keeping track of the changes.

Here is the code:

```
let context = SqlFunctions.Sql.GetDataContext()         
    let engeneering = context.HumanResources.Department.Individuals.``1``   
    engeneering.Name <- "Eng."
    context.SubmitUpdates()
```

`SqlFunction.Sql` implementation is as follows:

```
module SqlFunctions
open FSharp.Data.Sql
type Sql = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER, 
                            "Server=************;Database=AdventureWorks2014;Trusted_Connection=True;">
```

Comment: did you look at the documentation at https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/crud.html?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community!

While SqlDataProvider is an excellent tool, if you're open to it, I'd recommend using some simpler constructs.

We'll accomplish this by looking directly at your problem scope, and in the true nature of F#, write ourselves some nice little functions to make the end result clean & simple.

Our end goals is supporting syntax like this:

```ml
// Define a reusable "update department" function
let updateDepartment departmentId name connStr = 
    use conn = newConnection connStr
    exec 
        "UPDATE HumanResources.Department SET Name = @name WHERE DepartmentId = @departmentId"  
        [ ("departmentId", departmentId); ("name", name) ] 
        conn      

let connStr = "..."
updateDepartment 1 "eng" connStr |> ignore
```

To accomplish this, you actually need very little code, which is one of the major benefits of F#. We know we need:

- A way to *create connections* (i.e. connection factory)
- A way to *execute statements* (i.e. `INSERT`, `UPDATE`)
- A way to *query records* (i.e. `SELECT`)

```ml
module SQL =
    open System.Data
    open System.Data.SqlClient

    let newConnection connectionString =
        let conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString)
        conn.Open()
        conn
    
    let createParameter (cmd: SqlCommand) (name, value) =
        let p = cmd.CreateParameter()
        p.ParameterName <- name
        p.Value <- value
        p

    let addParameter (cmd: SqlCommand) (p : SqlParameter) = 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p) |> ignore

    let newCommand sql parameters conn =        
        let cmd = new SqlCommand(connection = conn, cmdText = sql)
        cmd.CommandType <- CommandType.Text        
        
        let createParam = createParameter cmd
        let addParam = addParameter cmd
        parameters 
        |> Seq.iter (fun p -> p |> createParam |> addParam)
        cmd 
    
    let exec sql param conn =
        let cmd = newCommand sql param conn
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    let query sql param map conn =
        let cmd = newCommand sql param conn
        use rd = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        [ while rd.Read() do
            yield map rd ]
```

Comment: Why is the code in the question not working? What are the reasons, not to use the data provider and to hand code the interaction instead? I think this answer would improve, if it elaborated on those questions.